# PHP is updating a database index that doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

On my main page, when someone signs-in, i have jQuery using AJAX to 'talk' to a PHP file, and the same for when they sign-out. But, when they sign out, it is supposed to update a database index with the time they left. If they database entry for their last name doesn't exist (meaning, they didn't sign-in), it is supposed to return an error. Instead, the PHP file is saying that it IS updating a non-existant database index. i am using IF statements to achieve this. and for some reason it thinks the index does exist. I've checked the database that it is writing to and the indexes it's supposed to be updating don't exist.

Here's my code:

```
if ($Type == 1)
{
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","----","----", "----");
if (!$mysqli)
    $Type = 3;


$Select = $mysqli->query("SELECT Time_Out FROM " . $Date . " WHERE Last_Name = '" . $LName . "'");
$Row = $Select->fetch_assoc();
$Row2 = $Row['Time_Out'];
if ($Row2 !== "-1") $Type = 4;


if ($Type == 1)
    {if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Date . " SET Time_Out='" . $Time . "' WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'"))
        {}
     else
        {$Type = 5;}
    }

$Select = $mysqli->query("SELECT Time_In FROM " . $Date . " WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
$Row = $Select->fetch_assoc();
$Row2 = $Row['Time_In'];
$Time2 = explode(":",$Row2);
$Hour2 =  $Hour - $Time2[0];

if ($mysqli->query("SELECT Hours FROM Names WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'"))
    {$Select = $mysqli->query("SELECT Hours FROM Names WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
     $Row = $Select->fetch_assoc();
     $Row3 = $Row['Hours'];
     $Auto += 1;}

$Time3 = 60-$Time2[1];
if ($Hour != 21) $Time4 = $Min;
$Time5 = $Time3+$Time4;
if ($Time2[0]+1 != $Hour)
    {$Time5 = $Time5+60;}
$Total = $Time5+intval($Row3);

if ($Type == 1)
{
if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE Names SET Hours = '" . $Total . "' WHERE Last_Name = '" . $LName . "'"))
    {$Auto += 1;}
else
    {$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Names (Last_Name, First_Name, Hours) VALUES ('" . $LName . "', '" . $FName . "', '" . $Total . "')");}
}


$mysqli->close();
}

if ($Type == 1) echo "Thank you " . $FName . " " . $LName . " for signing out! See you next time!";
if ($Type == 2) echo "The entered Student ID# is invalid. Please try again!";
if ($Type == 3) echo "An unexpected error has occured. Please try again!";
if ($Type == 4) echo "You have already signed out today!" . $Auto;
if ($Type == 5) echo "You didn't sign in today.";
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day

Comment: @Dagon Well it's tedious to post it 10 times a day. Perhaps if one person a day fixed it, I would only have to post it 9 times a day.

Comment: @njk then Don't for the love of Buddha!

Comment: Buddha would want me to better other people. If I don't inform them that they're using deprecated functions, I don't better them.

Comment: its just spam, just stop.

Comment: Okay, first, Thank You So Very Much For The Help............... Second, i've updated it to the new mysqli and it still has the same probelem. Mind helping me now?

Comment: Dagon, theres no reason for him to stop, just stop reading it, its not spam.

Comment: Well, for the regular user it's spam. But for the user making the mistake, it's definitely not spam, but a very useful advice. Isn't that also what SO is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE sql statement will return true, even if it doesn't find any matches (it still runs correctly, it just updates 0 rows).

Change this:

```
if ($Type == 1)
{if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Date . " SET Time_Out='" . $Time . "' WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'"))
    {}
else
    {$Type = 5;}
}
```

To this:

```
if ($Type == 1) {
    if ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM " . $Date . " WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'")->num_rows > 0)
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Date . " SET Time_Out='" . $Time . "' WHERE Last_Name='" . $LName . "'");
    else
        $Type = 5;
}
```

You run the select query to first determine if the record exists (if num_rows property of the result is > 0) and based on that either update the record or set your return value to 5.